# Images not getting changed with NSTimer

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

This is my code

```
- (void)updateCounterImage:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    static int count = 0;
    count += 1;
    int crb = 6 - count;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipad_game_timer_digit-%d.png", crb]];

    if ( count == 6)
        [timer release];

    [countTime setImage:image];
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    correctLevel.hidden = YES;
    incorrectLevel.hidden = YES;
    incorrectAnswer.hidden = YES;
    correctAnswer.hidden = YES;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateCounterImage:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

}

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *countTime;
    NSTimer *timer;
}


@end
```

The problem is my imageView is not changing its image for countime.

Comment: `[image release];` will crash one day: `[UIImage imageNamed:]` return an autoreleased instance. Please read Cocoa's memory management guidelines.

Comment: Furthermore, that ugly if chain shall be replaced by `image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipad_game_timer_digit-%d.png", count]];`

Comment: @unmar you're welcome. What I generally suggest to newcomers to iOS is that in order to develop good programming practices, one must not directly jump into iOS development - I strongly encourage reading a good C book/tutorial (K&R C is excellent) and *mastering* C before all the confusing Cocoa stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `repeats` to `NO` in the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` which means the timer will only tick once.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCounterImage:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```